# Limit number of rows inserted in a MySQL DB table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to limit the number of rows inserted in a table of my DB.

I 'd like to implement a logic to check if the limit is reached when a new insert is executed: if the max number of records is reached I will delete the oldest record in the table.

I tried to implement this with a trigger as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20313285/1061499), but I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'tableName' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

So how can I implement this?

**NOTE** I'm using MySQL v5.7.25

Comment: Why not just fill up the table, and then only execute updates?

Comment: @Strawberry please, can you elaborate this in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment,  why not just fill up the table, and then only execute updates?

E.g.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,val CHAR(1)
,ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO my_table (val) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO my_table (val) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO my_table (val) VALUES ('c');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | val  | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | a    | 2019-05-20 09:54:09 |
|  2 | b    | 2019-05-20 09:54:15 |
|  3 | c    | 2019-05-20 09:54:19 |
+----+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE my_table SET val = 'd' ORDER BY ts, id LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | val  | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | d    | 2019-05-20 09:54:37 |
|  2 | b    | 2019-05-20 09:54:15 |
|  3 | c    | 2019-05-20 09:54:19 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

MySQL does not allow this, see [Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions)
All other major DBMS support this feature so hopefully MySQL will add this support soon.

In this case you may handle this in pragmatically whatever you prefer.

```
Before insert data just check total number of row of that table. If reach rows limit, then call delete method.
```